# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not working when connecting through Android

Tags: php, forms, http-status-code-404

I am working on my computer with localhost.My form is

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" role="form">
```

Now, when I connect my android phone on the same network and punch in the ip address of my computer, on submission of form it says `404 not found`. That is because it is trying to reach the web address

> http://my.ip.address/%3c?php%20echo%20htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?%3E

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there is no reason to use:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"
```

Just use the following, if your wanting to point the form back to the page:

```
action=""
```

Comment: You should check php is enabled, from the string `http://my.ip.address/%3c?php%20echo%20htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?%3E` it looks like its not getting parsed and is being url encoded by the browser. But take note of my answer, ive never used `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ever in a single line of code ive ever written.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. the php is enabled on my server, and it works fine if I do a localhost on my computer. But from another device(in this case, my celphone) it is not working.